# How to populate listDataHeader in an expandable list view with Data from database?

Tags: android

I'm new to android development. I found this tutorial about expandable listview but it's only from a fixed data. Then after some search, I was able to set the listDataChild with data from my database. But now I'm stuck on How I can populate listDataHeader with Data from database.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
public class Manage_Students extends Activity {

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
    Cursor cursor;
    private LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.students);

        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

        // get Instance  of Database Adapter
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();


        // preparing list data
        prepareListData();

        listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

        // setting list adapter
        expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
    /*
     * Preparing the list data
     */
    private void prepareListData() {
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

         listDataHeader.add("Subject");  



           List<String> audio = loginDataBaseAdapter.retrievevalue("g");  

           listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),audio); // Header, Child data  
    }
}
```

and my adapter:

```
  public List<String> retrievevalue(String value)  

    {  
        ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();  



        Cursor cu=db.rawQuery("SELECT Section from Sections where Subjid ='"+value+"'",null);  
        cu.moveToFirst();  


        if (!cu.isAfterLast())  
        {  
            do  
            {  


   dataList.add(cu.getString(0));  

            }  

            while (cu.moveToNext());  
            cu.close();  
        }  

        // return the ArrayList that holds the data collected from  
        // the database.  
        return dataList;  
    //        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add or populate child data from this method as base adapter thinks of getting the child data and group data at the same time. So, create your own custom adapter and pass only parent or group data in it and when the group data is clicked, you add child data from there.